# Partition of a topological space generated by a subset of a basis

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm reading a paper and the following lemma is proven:

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{X})$ be a measurable space, let $(\mathcal{Y},\tau)$ be a topological space with a countable basis, and let $(\mathcal{Z},d)$ be a metric space. Let further $f: \mathfrak{X}\times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{Z}$ be a function such that $f(\cdot,y)$ is measurable for every $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for every $x\in \mathfrak{X}$. Then $f$ is $\mathfrak{X}\otimes \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{Y})$ measurable.

The proof starts by considering an enumeration $\{ \mathcal{U}_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ of a basis of $\tau$. Then it says: for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\{ E_{n,1},\dots,E_{n,k(n)}\}$ denote the partition of $\mathcal{Y}$ generated by $\{\mathcal{U}_1,\dots,\mathcal{U}_n\}$.

**My question is**: what does this last bit mean? As in, what is the definition of: "the partition of $\mathcal{Y}$ generated by $\{\mathcal{U}_1,\dots,\mathcal{U}_n\}$".

I tried looking it up online but had no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{U}=\{\mathcal{U}_k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$. For each $y\in\mathcal{Y}$ let $\mathfrak{U}(y)=\{\mathcal{U}_k\in\mathfrak{U}:y\in\mathcal{U}_k\}$. For $y_0,y_1\in\mathcal{Y}$ write $y_0\sim y_1$ if and only if $\mathfrak{U}(y_0)=\mathfrak{U}(y_1)$; clearly $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{Y}$, so it generates a partition of $\mathcal{Y}$ into its equivalence classes; that’s the partition in question.

Much more informally, two points of $\mathcal{Y}$ are in the same piece of the partition if and only if they belong to exactly the same members of $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept the answer in $3$ minutes once SE lets me do it.

Comment: @Reveillark: You’re welcome!